# Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, android

app crashes on this error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.example.haji.UploadWallpaper.onCreate(UploadWallpaper.java:60)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6906)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2850)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2962)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1684)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6661)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1106)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.haji-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.haji-1/lib/arm64,
>   /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source) 
>           at com.example.haji.UploadWallpaper.onCreate(UploadWallpaper.java:60) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6906) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2850) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2962) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1684) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6661) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1106) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)

And here's my build gradle

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
```

Comment: Update your dependencies. `firebase-ui-database` is on 4.2.0, `firebase-database` is on 16.0.1, `firebase-ui-auth` is on 4.2.0, `firebase-auth` is on 16.0.3, `firebase-storage` is on 16.0.4, `play-services-auth` is on 16.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and tried many things. I suggest two things which can solve your problem.
1. try adding this in your project build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
        google()
        maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
        jcenter()
    }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

if this doesn't solve problem then:
2. then in your gradle I can see Firebase versions are different. try implement save versions`enter code here`